# Why can I add random code to my Ruby class definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was learning some Rspec stuff and accidentally introduced some code into my model class which I expected to create an error. But to my surprise there were non.

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :country, :person_id, :street, :zip
  validates_presence_of :city, :zip, :street
  before_save :setDefaultCountry

  # -- Beginning strange code --

  if true
     puts "Hey! I shouldn't be able to do this"
  end       

  # -- End of strange code --

  private   
  def setDefaultCountry
    if self.country.blank?
      self.country = "US"
    end
  end
end
```

This is the rails console output:

```
Arman$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3p194 :001 > a = Address.new
Hey! I shouldn't be able to do this
 => #<Address id: nil, street: nil, city: nil, zip: nil, country: nil, person_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :002 >
```

Why isn't ruby complaining about strange code being added inside the class definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how ruby works. You don't think that `attr_accessible` should cause error, do you? But this is just a regular method call! [Here's its source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class)

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 1083
def attr_accessible(*attributes)
  write_inheritable_attribute(:attr_accessible, 
                              Set.new(attributes.map(&:to_s)) + (accessible_attributes || []))
end
```

You can run arbitrary ruby code in the class definition. This is a feature, not a bug :)

Comment: Actually `attr_accessible` is a `Hash`. So I see it as initialising a field?

Comment: What do you mean, "is a hash"?

Comment: I mean it prints `Hash` when I try `puts attr_accessible.class`

Comment: I guess you know the answer: some people neglect to study Ruby before delving in Rails. They just think than Hartl's tutorial will give them all. Big delusion!

Comment: @Arman: you're poking the wrong attr_accessible. See my updated answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I saw your answer, thanks. What's happening here is a strange concept relative to other languages I know.

Comment: btw, I notice in the source code the use of * and &. Where can I learn about their use cases?

Comment: About attr_accessible being Hash: `attr_accessible` is a method, so by calling its `.class` you just obtain the class of the last statement's result in this method. This method isn't supposed to return something and a user -- to get its result.

Comment: @Arman: The former is the splat operator. Google it. You can read about the latter [here](http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html).

Answer (score 3):

Because `class` block only introduces a new context for execution of code. Ruby is Ruby, not C++ - don't treat it as such. If we want to execute some code during class definition, why do you think we shouldn't be able to? You can execute code just fine inside it - and during this, `self` will point at the `Class` object that represents your class, instead of any instance of its class. This allows you great flexibility and is one of the big things in what makes Ruby monkey-patchable (which is a plus from the perspective of Rubyists, even though many others frown at the practice).